# Sort Magento Collection by Attribute Option Value?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, mage

I have rewritten `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`:

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('product_type', 'ASC', true);
```

Where the `product_type` attribute has an option `value=>key`:

```
<option value="515">Mount</option>
<option value="624" selected="selected">Accessories</option>
```

I want my product collection to sort by option key and not by option value text.

Is this possible with `AttributeToSort`?